# how to filter in node.js for getting json object value which has xml data

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image]

```
const result = array.stores.filter(y=> y.store_id == store_id);
console.log("result")
```

I tried this but no value is filtered. Can anyone suggest me simple method to filter XML data and get the value whatever is searched.

Another problem is how to convert XML data to JSON data in the node

Comment: You cannot filter on xml. Convert that xml string to json first

Comment: var filteredArray = getdata
    .filter(element => element.stores
    .some(subElement => subElement.store_id === postData.store_id || subElement.store_name === postData.store_name)
    )
    .map(element => {
    let n = Object.assign({}, element, {'stores': element.stores.filter(
        subElement => subElement.store_id === postData.store_id || subElement.store_name === postData.store_name 
    )})
    return n;
    })

for json data filtering only